# How do you "branch" a Unity project

Tags: unity

How do you branch a unity project?

Suppose you have Game Project A, and say there is variant A' that requires a large convoluted plugin. But the idea is also that you want to keep developing this without the plugin getting in the way, for the other variants - say A and A'' - that don't require it.

Comment: You set up a repository and then create a branch for that. I suggest you look up tutorials on git repository or source control since it can get a bit complicated.

Comment: right, so i wonder if there is a customized tutorial for this specific use case

Comment: Git is a tool universally used in programming, so by just typing git tutorial you can start learning. There are even "unity git tutorials" on youtube which are basically the same as ordinary git tutorials but with unity in the background.